# Getting sub data from a list of facilities

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query and would like some help if possible. Thanks in advance.

I have a table of facility data (~100k rows) that I am getting from a public source.  That data contains several records for what I would consider to be the same place (same name, city, state), they just have different suite numbers.  The other interesting bit of code is that I have a selection counter on the data that I increment anytime someone chooses one of the facilities.  This way, I can use the selection count along with some other weight calculations to make results show higher in a list.

What I am trying to do is write a query that when someone enters a search query, it will show only one record for the facility, the one with the highest selection count, and omit the rest.

Note: I do not want to do any preprocessing to the data as it is going to get re-loaded monthly.

Scheama:
ID
Name
Address 1
Address 2
City
State
Zip
Phone
Selection Count

Example Search: "women"

```
ID  Name                        City        State   Selection Count
1   Brigham & Women's Hospital  Boston      MA      22
2   Brigham & Women's Hospital  Cambridge   MA      0
3   Brigham & Women's Hospital  Boston      MA      5
4   Brigham & Women's Hospital  Boston      MA      1
5   Brigham & Women's Hospital  Orlando     FL      3
6   Woman's Hospital of Detroit Detroit     MI      100
7   Brigham & Women's Hospital  Boston      MA      0
8   Woman's Hospital of Detroit Detroit     MI      55
```

What I'd like is a resultset that contains 1, 2, 5, 6

1,3,4,7 Are the same so bring back the top selection count. Same for 6 and 8.

I am sure that there is a having and a top clause in here somewhere, but I have not been able to get this to do what I want.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us any sql that you've tried to get working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select id, name, city, state, selcount from t 
where exists
(
  select 1 from
  (select name, city, state, max(selcount) selcount
     from t 
    group by name, city, state) s
  where s.name = t.name and s.city = t.city and s.state = t.state and s.selcount = t.selcount
)
```

I've built a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6b4c/6) for this to show a working example.

Comment: Wow! First time poster on here and can't believe the response time.  Thank you very much N West!!! I spent way longer than I would have liked to on this the other day.  Your answer is perfect.  And thanks for showing me SQL Fiddle.  Great tool!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT ID, Name, City, State, [Selection Count],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, City, State ORDER BY [Selection Count] DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM YourTable
)
SELECT ID, Name, City, State, [Selection Count]
    FROM cteRowNum
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```